# Struts2 action not getting resolved inside osgi bundle

Tags: struts2, osgi, bundle

I am using struts2osgi bundle and trying to embed osgi container inside my web container. I have deployed my actions inside a bundle. In the action bundle I have put my action classes, my struts.xml, Spring xml file and manifest file with the following  structure:

```
|-bundle
    |-com
       |-HelloAction.class
    |-struts.xml
    |-META-INF
       |-MANIFEST.MF
       |-spring
         |-spring.xml
```

Now when I am trying to deploy the webapp by putting this bundle inside the web app it is giving me error "HelloAction can not be loaded". But it is present inside the same bundle. I don't know why this is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to export the package since either the spring dm or the struts2osgi bundles need to get a hold on it.